# is there a customization point for webview in android to alter the response content before it been rendered?

Tags: webview

I'm making a custom simple `web browser` for Android and needed to capture the content of every page the user browses and manipulate it before rendering so that it displays as expected.

What is the best place to listen to or be hooked to, and how can I get the `html response` before `webview` render it.